# Unable to use DialPipe in package go-winio

Tags: windows, macos, go

In my code I imported a package `"github.com/Microsoft/go-winio"`
And when ever I try to call `winio.DialPipe` It says DialPipe not declared by winio

I want to access named pipe in windows

I am using MacOs(M1) to code.

I tried reading the microsoft implementation and there I can find they have delared `DialPipe` in a file named `pipe.go`. What should I do in this situation??

Comment: Have you set [`GOOS`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Environment_variables) to `windows`? `go-winio` uses [build constraints](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Build_constraints) so most functions will not be available when other operating systems are targeted (it appears cross compiling [may work](https://github.com/microsoft/go-winio/issues/52)).